# Displaying a dialog in an onClick event results in "android Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application" error

Tags: dialog, onclick

There are a bunch of posts referring to the error "android Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application", but they all have to do with using the context during the Activity creation process.

I'm trying to display a dialog from the activity that a user clicks a button in.  Toasts show up fine, so there isn't any reason why a Dialog wouldn't show.

The only solution I have seen is to delay the display of the dialog using some thread, but that doesn't make sense when attempting to display a dialog from an onClick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I just solved my own problem.  I just need to pass THIS as opposed to the Context.